# How to search by first td text and clicking in seconds td href by JUnit, Webdriver?

Tags: selenium, junit

```
<div class="row">
<div class="row">
 <table>
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td class="list-text">
     <div style="background-color: transparent;">Testing this function</div>
    </td>
    <td class="list-buttons" rowspan="2">
     <a href="javascript:;">Config</a>
     <a class="edit-button" href="javascript:;">Edit</a>
     <a class="save-button" href="javascript:;" style="display:none;">Save</a>
     <a href="javascript:;">Delete</a>
    </td>
   </tr>
  <tr>
 </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
```

I need to find the element which contains the text "Testing this function" and click to link "Config".

Can't find a way to do it.

Edited: Found a way to do it:

```
By.xpath("//div[@class='row']/table/tbody/tr[td/div[contains(.,'Testing')]]/td[2]/a[contains(.,'Config')]")
```

But maybe someone has a better solution for this?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! You'll need to add a bit more info if you want a good response — What have you tried so far, & what happened when you did? & how was this different to what you expected to happen? (Based on your reading of the documentation, ideally… ;) ). If you add these to the question and also tidy your code sample (indentation/syntax) you'll be a lot more likely to get some people putting the effort in.

Comment: These coments sometimes help to.
I find a way to locate element. Add it to orgianl post to, maybe someone have better solution.

By.xpath("//div[@class='row' ]/table/tbody/tr[td/div[contains(.,'Testing')]]/td[2]/a[contains(.,'Config')]")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have to use text, my preference would be;

By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'Testing')]]//a[contains(text(),'Config')]") .

I prefer using "text()" to "." just for readability. Apologies if "." is actually a better approach which I wasn't aware of.

Also unless you have a specific reason, I would avoid using tightly coupled xpath. E.g. I have not used  " td[2]", instead I have said the"a" can be anywhere within in the "div"

Comment: If I use your suggested xpath it do not locate element "Congig"! I think it is because //div[contains(text(),'Testing')] went into first <tr><td><div> where don't have element like <a>.